How to truly compare two dataframes based on a key column?
My inputs are two dataframes:
import pandas as pd

df_having = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['ID_01', 'ID_01', 'ID_01', 'ID_01', 'ID_02', 'ID_03', 'ID_03', 'ID_05', 'ID_06', 'ID_06'], 'NAME': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'E', 'B', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'A'], 'TYPE': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'A', 'C', 'A', 'B', 'F', 'A', 'A'], 'CATEGORY': [1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]})
df_tohave = pd.DataFrame({'ID': ['ID_01', 'ID_01', 'ID_02', 'ID_02', 'ID_03', 'ID_03', 'ID_03', 'ID_04', 'ID_05'], 'NAME': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'E', 'A', 'D'], 'TYPE': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'D', 'G'], 'CATEGORY': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2, 3, 3, 2]})

I'm trying to do comparison based on the column 'ID' so that I end up with third dataframe (at the very right of the image below) :

df_having reflects the actual situation of the system and df_tohave is what this one should have.
The FLAG can have the following values:

NO_ACTION: The 'ID' has the correct 'NAME', 'TYPE' and 'CATEGORY' in df_having
TO_CREATE: the 'ID' is missing in df_having and exists in df_tohave
TO_UPDATE: the 'ID' exists in df_having but at least one of the fields 'NAME', 'TYPE' and 'CATEGORY' is incorrect
TO_DELETE: the 'ID' exists in df_having and not in df_tohave

The FIELDS are simply the fields concerned by the FLAG.
When building the comparison dataframe, if the flag is 'TO_DELETE' we grab the row from df_having, otherwise we get it from df_tohave.
I made a try but the resulting dataframe has 34 rows while it should be 13 and the majority of flags are wrong.
df_merged = pd.merge(df_having, df_tohave, on=['ID', 'NAME', 'TYPE', 'CATEGORY'], how='outer', indicator=True)
df_merged['FLAG'] = df_merged['_merge'].map({'both': 'NO_ACTION', 'left_only': 'TO_DELETE', 'right_only': 'TO_CREATE'})
df_merged['FIELDS'] = df_merged['FLAG'].map({'NO_ACTION': 'NONE', 'TO_DELETE': 'ALL', 'TO_CREATE': 'ALL'})

import functools

cols = ['NAME', 'TYPE', 'CATEGORY']
df_diff = functools.reduce(lambda left, right: pd.merge(left, right, on='ID', how='outer', suffixes=('_having', '_tohave')), 
              [df_having[['ID'] + cols], df_tohave[['ID'] + cols]])

for col in cols:
    df_diff[f'{col}_diff'] = df_diff[f'{col}_having'] != df_diff[f'{col}_tohave']

df_diff['FIELDS'] = df_diff[[f'{col}_diff' for col in cols]].dot(pd.Index(cols) + ' & ').str.strip(' & ')
df_diff = df_diff[df_diff['FIELDS'] != ''].assign(FLAG='TO_UPDATE')

df_comparison = pd.concat([df_merged, df_diff[['ID', 'NAME_tohave', 'TYPE_tohave', 'CATEGORY_tohave', 'FLAG', 'FIELDS']].rename(columns={
    'NAME_tohave': 'NAME', 'TYPE_tohave': 'TYPE', 'CATEGORY_tohave': 'CATEGORY'})]).drop(columns='_merge').reset_index(drop=True)

Do you guys know what I'm doing wrong?
Can anyone provide a solution?

What logic determines which incorrect ID in df_having qualifies for "TO_UPDATE". E.g., for ID_01, you have ('ID_01', 'A', 'B', 2) as the update for ('ID_01', 'A', 'B', 3). Why can it not be the update for ('ID_01', 'A', 'A', 3). Difference: 1 field vs. 2 fields? Ok, so what needs to happen if the second option is ('ID_01', 'A', 'C', 2). And what if we have 2 similar options in df_having  matching 2 similarly different options in df_tohave: which option from df_tohave would get mapped as the update of which option from df_having, and why?

Thanks Ouroboros for taking time and sorry for my late reply. To answer your first question, ('ID_01', 'A', 'B', 2) is the update for ('ID_01', 'A', 'B', 3) and not for ('ID_01', 'A', 'A', 3) because we need to prioritize the rows with the fewer fields to update. 1 field in the former Vs. 2 fields for the latter. You also said "what needs to happen if the second option is ('ID_01', 'A', 'C', 2)?", do you mean in df_tohave ? If yes, then ('ID_01', 'A', 'C', 2) is the update for ('ID_01', 'A', 'A', 3).

And for the second part of your first comment "2 similar options in df_having matching 2 similarly different options in df_tohave", can you provide an example please ?

Using 2 values to keep it simple, all for same ID. In df_having I have [('A', 'B'), ('B','C'), ('B', 'E')] and in df_tohave: [('A', 'A'), ('B', 'B'), ('D', 'D')]. I could say: 3 updates: ('A', 'B') -> ('A', 'A') (1 field), ('B', 'C') -> ('B', 'B') (1 field), and ('B', 'E') -> ('D', 'D') (2 fields). But the start is arbitrary and matters. I could have started: ('A', 'B') -> ('B', 'B') (1 field), but now I have ('B','C') and ('B', 'E') to map on ('A', 'A') and ('D', 'D'). which would both be 2 fields and no reason why one is a more obvious update of either.

So, I think the difficulty of determining the "TO_UPDATE" rows is being underestimated. I assume you are thinking of performance here, but it would of course be way easier to look at it from a "TO_DELETE" vs. "TO_CREATE" perspective only: [('A', 'B'), ('B','C'), ('B', 'E')] -> not in df_tohave, so "TO_DELETE". And then for [('A', 'A'), ('B', 'B'), ('D', 'D')] -> not in df_having, so "TO_CREATE". And we would be done :)

I think I understand what you mean in your second comment. If there is a tie in the number of fields to update, then we pick an arbitrary pair of rows (1 from df_having and 1 from df_tohave) and flag it "TO_UPDATE" and the other one(s) as "TO_DELETE". And for your third comment, believe me my friend it's not about performance at all. It's just how this problem should be tackled. And I agree with you about the most simple option which will be to have only two flags. I can even say that i don't care about performance because the number of rows of the two inputs is always between 1 and 100.
